# how see indexes on continues aggregate?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I just created an index on my continuing aggregate. I am using version 2.9.2.
Create an index with this command.
`'CREATE INDEX idx_slug_time ON continues_aggregate (slug, time asc);`
but nowhere can I find it, and my free storage after this command is near 20%. then it must be created. but nowhere can I see it.

I tried `\d continues_aggregate` and  `select *from pg_indexes where tablename is not like 'pg%'`.

no improve in performance shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes are created under `_timescaledb_internal` schema where continuous aggregate data is stored

If you want to drop the index `idx_slug_time`  , below is sample query

```
DROP INDEX _timescaledb_internal.idx_slug_time;
```

Please refer the documentation link below for more details on indexes

https://docs.timescale.com/use-timescale/latest/continuous-aggregates/create-index/